# How to allow python to edit a open file on windows?

Tags: python, windows, file

I've searched for this, but all I could find was how to open and edit files using pyhton. And that's not what I need.

I want to edit the permissions of a file so python can edit them while they are open, like I can do it on a Linux OS (or so I was told I could).

Thanks in advance.